# Set Progress Dialog properly in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, dialog

I currently trying to show a progress dialog on OnclickListener of a Dialogbox since my items are taking too long to fetch from Server.
  I use Async task as suggested here ([Android progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713222/android-progress-dialog)) and this post ([android problem with progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370070/android-problem-with-progress-dialog)) to show progress dialog  The progress dialog is shown , however the code returns exception when it goes to do background that " Looper is not set". And when I set looper nothing happens.

I am not sure at this stage what is it that I am doing wrong.

```
public void firstMethod()
{
    final CustomObj obj = getCustomObj();//not imp

        Messages.getInstance().showAlert(MainActivity.this, "message", false, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                gotoAnotherPge(obj);

            }

        });


}   

public void gotoAnotherPge(final CustomObject obj)
{

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

     new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean>()
    {

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

            pd.setMessage(String.format(Statics.getText(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dictionary, "subscriptions_loading_unsubscribing")));
            pd.show();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params)
        {       


            try{
                Looper.prepare();
                final LocalPopulator lp = new LocalPopulator(MainActivity.this, 0)
                {

                    @Override
                    public void populate()
                    {
                       List<Serializable> items = Arrays.asList(getItemHere(obj));

                        List<Serializable> listItems = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
                       listItems.addAll(items);
                        Serializable[] sItems = listItems.toArray(new Serializable[menuItems.size()]);
                        result = sItems;
                    }
                };
                showNextPage(true, 1, 0, lp);

                Looper.loop();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                /*
                 * The task failed
                 */
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }


    };
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread (new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            // dismiss the progressdialog
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Well I couln't find any answer to why the Spinner (Progress Dialog) is not showing. It is somehow been put in the background for populater to finish first and then it is displayed.

Comment: I made a work around that rather than using populator on main thread, I created service populater, that runs as a background task. Also now I show the Progress dialog after loading the new screen and then load the data.